# PHP to SQL Date/Time conversion

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I need to get 2020-04-24T10:17 in this format 2020-04-24 10:17:00:000 for inserting into MSSQL datetime field.

This is what I've tried:
`echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s:u", strtotime($dateTime));`

`$dateTime` contains 2020-04-24T10:17 but the above code returns 1969-12-31 19:00:00:000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. Make sure that $dateTime has the actual time.

Tested on php 7.0

```
$dateTime = "2020-04-24T10:17";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s:u", strtotime($dateTime));
```

Comment: Well now I'm getting the correct value. I'm not sure what changed though. Thank you for verifying that it works properly.